# Only allow permission to functions and procedures but not the underlying tables used by them

Tags: postgresql

I am working with postgres and have made many functions and procedures to view and manipulate data. I am wondering if there is a way to grant a user access to these functions and procedures without directly giving them access to the underlying tables that are manipulated by these functions and procedures.

I have looked into SECURITY DEFINER but upon realizing that it cannot use transaction support I have been trying to find other ways to implement this.

If it is not possible to give access only to functions and procedures, what are some other avenues out there, if any? All of the database communication for my application will go through my backend which will only call my functions and procedures, but I just wanted a way to enforce this at the database level, not just an application level, for extra security.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it cannot use transaction support*"? Sure you can use such functions in transactions.

Comment: Why do you think that functions or procedures don’t have support for transactions? What kind of functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Postgres role attributes available are described in [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createrole.html)

Comment: I was looking into articles such as [this one](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2499960) and assumed that since procedures are executed within a transaction that a procedure could not roll back if an error occurs. I have also already created a user role that still needs access to the underlying tables that the procedures and functions use even though the role has been granted execution.

Comment: "*A `SECURITY DEFINER` procedure cannot execute transaction control statements (for example, `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`, depending on the language).*" means that you cannot run a transaction inside a procedure, but you still can run the procedure inside a transaction.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarity! Is _SECURITY DEFINER_ standard for making sure a user role can only access functions and procedures but not the underlying tables used by them along with granting the user role the ability to execute said functions and procedures?

Comment: @ohShoes Yes. The alternative is using views, which traditionally behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is very easy and simple to provide access to function & procedures, without giving access to actual data. For this all you need to do is create [USER ROLES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/database-roles.html).

An example is as follows:

- [Create Role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createrole.html):

  CREATE ROLE my_role LOGIN;
- Permissions:

  GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE/FUNCTION myProcedureOrFunction() TO my_role;

Comment: I have created a role for users and granted permission to all of my procedures and functions but when trying to execute them, I get the error 'permission denied for table 'table_name'' which is why I had to give the role access to the underlying tables but is not what I desired.

Comment: You need to grant certain privilege's to the roles created,

Comment: Here is what the grant statements look like: _GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION store.view_cart(user_cart_id integer) TO user;_ Is there something else that I need to grant on the user?